# Display View icon inside an encrypted lightning-inputField and on the click of that icon, unmask all the encrypted values in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have a requirement where I need a View icon inside lightning-inputField in a Lightning-record-edit-form. This field will hold masked values. When user clicks on the view icon, it should unmask the values in this field. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please see [ask] and [edit] this question to add information.

Comment: I am looking for options or approaches on how can I unmask the characters on the click of a button.